# How can I find duplicates in a list, and delete all duplicates except for a certain one?

Tags: python

I have a sorted list `dataPts` that is sorted based on the angle each point makes with the minimum Y value `minY` in `dataPts`, such as `[(0, 0), (10, 10), (20, 20) ... ]` (0, 0) being `minY`.

Then I create a new list `angles` which is a list of all those angles, for instance  `[0, 45, 45, ...]`.

You will notice that `angles` contains duplicate values, for instance `45, 45,`. What I want to do is locate the points in `dataPts` that share the same angle. I then want to delete those points, EXCEPT the one that is the furthest distance from  `minY` using a function that returns a value.

For example, `(10, 10)` and `(20, 20)` both have corresponding values in `angles`, which is `45`. How can I pick out the value with greater distance to `minY` which is `(20, 20)` and delete `(10, 10)`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
angles1 = [(0, 0), (10, 10), (20, 20)]
angles = [0, 45, 45]
dumy = {}
duplicates = []
for i,items in enumerate(angles):
    if (items not in dumy):
        dumy[items] = ""
    else:
        duplicates.append(i)
        if((angles[i-1] == items) and i-1 not in duplicates):
            duplicates.append(i-1)


for i in (duplicates):
    del angles1[i]
```

Suppose if you want to remove the only duplicates,  try the following code

```
for i,items in enumerate(angles):
    if (items not in dumy):
    dumy[items] = ""
    else:
    duplicates.append(i)
    del angles1[i] 
    if((angles[i-1] == items) and i-1 not in duplicates):
        del angles1[i-1]
```

Comment: That is indeed returning the duplicate values thanks! Using `duplicates`, how can I go through `angles1` and delete the points that can be found in `duplicates`?

Answer (score 1):

you could create a dict using the angles as keys, where the values are all of the elements with a given angle, then choose the max based on your distance function.

i.e. something like:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: [])

for angle, pt in zip(angles, dataPts):
    d[angle].append(pt)

result = [max(pt, key=my_dist_func) for angle, pt in d.items()]
```

Given the ymin and distance function you're describing, I think this works:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dataPts = [(0, 0), (10, 10), (20, 20) ]
angles = [0,45,45]
ymin = min((p[1] for p in dataPts))

d = defaultdict(lambda: [])

for angle, pt in zip(angles, dataPts):
    d[angle].append(pt)

result = [max(pt, key=lambda p: p[1]-ymin) for angle, pt in d.items()]
```